# Flutter Horizontal ListView-- how to 'jumpTo' selected Index

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview, scroll

I have ListView.builder with horizontal scrolling (a custom top navigation bar). As I scroll to the right and left, the 'selectedIndex' is changing, but the UI inside this widget isn't showing this change in position. I'd like to 'Jump To' the selected index upon swiping.

Here's how my ListView is currently updating its index:

```
    void onChanged(int index) {
        pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        setState(() {
          this.selectedIndex = index;
        });
      }
```

How can I accomplish this? Any guidance would mean a lot.

Thanks, A.V.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate selected item offset by item width and height and then use

```
 _gridViewController.jumpTo(calculatedOffset);
```